# fetchmail: fetch sent mail to sent folder, or fetch to a target folder

Tags: email, fetchmail

How can I configure fetchmail to fetch a folder to a specific target folder? Or at least not fetch to inbox? If it would fetch from sent to sent (or any folder to the same folder name) I'd be happy with it.

Fetching sent and putting them in my inbox and marking them as "new mail" would be crazy, now wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at a filtering solution such as *procmail*.

You can have *fetchmail* collect the mail from your IMAP or POP (or whatever) server and then specify in your `~/.fetchmailrc` configuration that it should deliver with `procmail` (see the `mda` setting in the manual). You would then set up *procmail* to filter the incoming mail into one or several mail boxes.

I'm just mentioning *procmail* because that's what I've been using for decades. I'm sure there are other mail filtering software out there.

Example *fetchmail* configuration:

```
poll mail.example.com
protocol imap
user "me.there" password "password" is "me.here"
mda "/opt/local/bin/procmail -m $HOME/.procmailrc"
```

Snippet from my `~/.procmailrc` (incomplete):

```
MAILDIR="$HOME/Dropbox/Mail"
DEFAULT="inbox/"
LOGFILE="$HOME/.procmail.log"

# [cut several lines]

:0
* ^List-Id:.*macports-changes.lists.macosforge.org
macports-changes/

:0
* ^List-Id:.*macports-users.lists.macosforge.org
macports-users/

# [etc.]
```

In your case, you would add a delivery receipt for mail that you've sent yourself. These would go into a separate folder.

Comment: Since I cannot yet comment (i lack reputation :-\\), I just want to add that using procmail is considered dangerous by some people : https://anarc.at/blog/2022-03-02-procmail-considered-harmful/, because it's mostly unmaintained and insecure.
I recommend reading this article before using it.